# Estouro de memória - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Ao tentar descompactar um arquivo zip de 500MB utilizando o package [archive](https://pub.dev/packages/archive), estou tendo problemas de memória (Out of memory).

Segue o código para avaliação e sugestão de alguma alternativa.

```
    unarchiveAndSave(var zippedFile) async {
    var bytes = zippedFile.readAsBytesSync();
    var archive = ZipDecoder().decodeBytes(bytes);

    for (var file in archive) {
      var fileName = '$_dir/${file.name}';

      if (file.isFile) {
        var outFile = File(fileName);
        print('File:: ${outFile.path}');
        outFile = await outFile.create(recursive: true);
        await outFile.writeAsBytes(file.content);
      }
    }
  }
```

O sistema descompacta boa parte do arquivo, porém, em dado momento o retorno que tenho é que perdeu a conexão com o emulador e em outros *Out of memory*.

Comment: Já tentou no dispositivo físico?

Comment: Sim, acontece a mesma coisa. Como isso não estava funcionando, mudei um pouco a abordagem e estou utilizando o package CachedNetworkPlugin, que já faz inclusive tratamento de erros quando vou baixar os arquivos na Internet. Antes a abordagem era baixar um arquivo compactado com todas as fotos, agora estou lendo as fotos diretamente do site. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho como testar aqui, mas tente usar a classe [InputFileStream](https://dart-pub.mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn/documentation/archive/2.0.2/archive_io/InputFileStream-class.html) configurando o bufferSize e depois chamar diretamente [decodeBuffer](https://dart-pub.mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn/documentation/archive/2.0.2/archive_io/ZipDecoder/decodeBuffer.html).

Comment: Estou tentado a achar isso como verdade ou próximo disso, mas do jeito que está não me parece extremamente útil. Parece mais um comentário do que uma resposta propriamente dita. Já faz quase 1 dia desde que isso foi postado, tem como testar agora para poder elaborar melhor?

Comment: Vou tentar essa abordagem mais tarde. No momento achei uma alternativa para contornar isso. Obrigado pela ajuda.